# Strategy to pay off revolving debt while building reserve savings fund?

Tags: united-states, savings, debt, debt-reduction, emergency-fund

We currently have about $16K cash. I'd like to have $30-35K+ for a ~6 month reserve. This will be a "single giant reserve fund" that will pay for large and/or unplanned expenses, frivolities like vacations, in addition to providing financial security/freedom in the event of hardship like job loss, medical expense, etc.

I know it will take time to get there. But it seems each time I reach some milestone (e.g., $20K, or briefly flirted with $25K) **we get hammered with some large, unexpected expense** which either saps the reserve fund, or adds to the debt.

Obviously, we should be *budgeting* for "unplanned expenses", and that's something I'm trying to work on as we've adjusted from two full-time incomes to one full-time + one part-time. The immediate concern is just getting out of the revolving debt, which should free up cash for building up the savings accounts or paying down other debts outstanding.

Examples over the last 12-18 months:

- $2000 for new hot water heater
- $2200 for vehicle repairs/maintenance (*mea culpa*, my Jeep is 14 years old, this should've been budgeted...)
- $2000 assessment for new parking lot on an "investment property"*
- $2300 for new washer/dryer **

<sub>* The "investment property" wasn't purchased as such. It's my wife's sole & separate from before we were married (I'm neither on title or mortgage). We have had one bad tenant in 11 years of renting it, and have never had to eat more than one mortgage payment between tenants. Rent covers the fixed expenses (mortgage, taxes, insurance, association dues).</sub>

<sub>** Both W&D were ~15 years old and have been on their last legs. Cheaper replacement options were available, but with considerably shorter expected lifespans (~10 years versus 25 years). We consider these more of an investment in the house itself (akin to a new roof, flooring, etc.) than a consumable. Feel free to disagree, but that was the rationale.</sub>

---

Total annual income is ~$130,000 but this is split unevenly between my full time salary ($100K), rental income ($10,000/year) and my wife's part-time income. I can provide additional detail re: income, expenses, assets, etc., if needed.

Our debt-utilization is under 25%, credit is generally quite favorable (774 Experian, 792 Transunion).

Current debts:

- Mortgage: $175K outstanding; 15 @ 2.875%, 12 years remaining.
- Mortgage ("Investment property"): $52K outstanding, ARM; 30 @ 5%, 15 years remaining
- Student Loans: $45,000 at 4% ($352 monthly payment)
- HELOC: $22,000 balance at 3.5%
- CC1: $3600 balance at 0% through December
- CC2: $2300 balance due Aug 28 to remain within grace period (this was an unplanned expense: new washer/dryer last week)

I am not asking how to get out from the condo mortgage, student loans, or even the HELOC, but simply for strategy to pay off the immediate obligations & credit cards, beyond which I can more comfortably divide our disposable income among those obligations + savings.

I had been planning to pay off the $3600 card over the next 90 days, but then our washer broke & we ended up with new washer & dryer. This expense will come from our current savings (it was put on a card solely for ease of purchase while we need to transfer $$ from savings to checking).

I'd like to pay off both CC's which amounts to a pretty staggering outlay in the next ~90 days of nearly $10K (we will have property taxes & homeowners insurance due September, totaling ~$4000 -- these were planned for, but the W&D were not!), which would basically cut our reserve/savings fund to barely one month's expenses.

**This is a pretty tough pill to swallow, but it seems like the way to go.** Like, the debt snowball approach; after zeroing out the CC accounts I should be able to redirect most of my budgeted "credit card bill payment" money ($1000-1500/month) to grow the reserve fund.

But this puts me in a cash position that is, well, way **less than I am really comfortable with**, and I fear the day that my 2005 Jeep will need to be replaced, or our central air unit breaks ($4500 to replace), or our driveway caves in, etc.

One alternative would be to consolidate the CC debts into the HELOC. I don't particularly like that, but it seems somehow more "manageable" provided we continue to pay it down aggressively (~$1000/month).

I could come up with an extra $500 monthly by temporarily (say, for the next 4-5 months) reducing my 401k contributions to the company match amount. I don't really want to do this, either, but there may be a case for doing so.

I don't feel particularly over-extended (assets > liabilities by a good margin, cash position & net worth increasing steadily, debt is going down).

We made a $52,000 down payment and have a 15-year note that pays down principal at the rate of ~$1000/month. So we have a nominally high mortgage payment (compared to the more popular 30-year note), but also considerably more equity. While this insulates us against downturns in the market, it comes at the expense of cash/liquidity.

I contribute about $750/month to my 401k, and we pay about $300 towards some life insurance policies, etc.

I figure lot of "average" people do not do one or more of these things, but we do all of them, and it's a bit of a double-edged sword: yes, we're saving for retirement, yes, we have well-funded 401k, yes we have strong equity position in real estate, but as a result of these savings/investments, sometimes feel cash-poor.

Comment: My first impression is that I'm concerned you are letting the details of the individual debt accounts vs cash distract you from the bigger and more concerning question: on the net (cash minus debt), in what direction are you going over the last 3, 6, 12 months? The fine details of whether you pay off a CC immediately with cash or draw it out over a few months is much less concerning than whether you are sinking or rising over all. No amount of allocating cash to savings or debt would fix a problem with too much expenses against income. Make sure that part isn't broken first.

Comment: @Kevin the "investment property" is a condo my wife bought several years before we were married (wife owns sole & separate). We are able to rent it out reliable at above our fixed expenses, and periodically we have to bite the bullet for maintenance/cleaning/etc. We married in 2008 when local real estate was like, 40% down from its peak. There was no way we could sell it at that time, and the ship has long since sailed on simply offering the bank a died in lieu or otherwise walking away from it.

Comment: Could you sell the condo now?  Prices have gone up a lot since then.

Comment: @BrianH over past 12 months, cash trending up (about $8-9K). total debts are trending down by a slightly larger amount (~$12K)

Comment: @RonJohn possibly, probably still worth less than she paid for it in 2004 (though more than she owes on it presently, we wouldn't stand to walk away with very much $$ but it would get rid of a potential source of uncertainty in the future... I'd feel more strongly about selling if we were really in a hair-on-fire situation, but otherwise I'm inclined to take the long position on it.

Comment: Still underwater?  I'm a bit surprised.  Maybe an appraisal would shed more light on the topic.

Comment: @RonJohn no, I doubt very much that we're underwater on the condo. But it is a small 1 bedroom, so, a tough sale in any market and she happened to buy at just about the peak of the early-2000s boom. If we could find a buyer, and not have to remove our tenant and eat a few months of mortgage expense in the process, we could probably net 10K.

Comment: You'd kill a bunch of debt, and reduce your worry.  Another thought is that the *current* real estate bubble might be ready to pop.

Comment: I'd say you may be living a bit above your needs. Did you need a $2300 W/D? wasn't there a more affordable model? Do you need a Jeep? (beside its value, which by its age is not that much now, it's also costing more than a smaller car in insurance, maintenance, gas, ...)

Comment: This should probably be a separate question, but is a 30-35k safety net even necessary/advisable? Assuming you have access to credit when you need it, is that credit itself not your safety net? Instead, by not dumping your savings into your loans, I think you're essentially paying 5% (ARM) interest on your 30-35k just to have it...

Comment: Ah, savings accounts interest rates are higher these days than i thought. Assuming you're getting around 2% on your account, it would be 5-2% that you're paying just to hold your money (= -3%)

Comment: The same line of thought would also apply to the investment property as well. Your costs there aren't just mortgage costs - rent, they're (mortgage - rent + repairs + property taxes + the interest you wouldn't pay if you sold it and dumped the money into paying other debt +/- any related tax credits)

Comment: @RonJohn why do you think theres currently a real estate bubble?

Comment: @DreamConspiracy I'm not at all an expert on that, but this is how I understood it from the movie "The Big Short": Remember the last bubble and the crash? They made laws to forbid that thing that made it possible, but now they're back to doing the same thing under a different name (it's called "_Bespoke Tranche Opportunity_" instead of "_collateralized debt obligation (CDO)_" now).

Comment: @R.Schmitz the last recession was not only caused by the existence of bs investments but more importantly by the amount of money that was in them (and in betting on their success). Even if these new things are as bad as what happened in the last recession, can you give some evidence that a similarly significant amount of money is in them?

Comment: @DreamConspiracy No, I can't. Like I said, I'm not a financial expert, only remembered this bit from the movie.

Comment: @Mars credit needs to be paid back, as far as safety nets go it's inferior to having cash or cash equivalent. all else equal of course it's better to have good credit than not, but it's even better to have good credit AND cash.

Comment: If it's not costing you a guaranteed $1000 a year, I don't see how it's better than cash, assuming you are roughly guaranteed the credit. 6 months is also double the suggested length of a safety net as I've heard in other answers on money.se, which makes me more dubious. That said, I'm new to finances, so there's a good chance I'm missing something. But at the moment, I only see your safety net as costing you about a grand a year and your investment property costing you possibly a good deal more (not including the burden of a risk). But that's why I'm here, to learn deeper concepts!

Comment: @Mars 3 mos is a great guideline and starting point. If you can get there, you're ahead of many people. But 6 or even 12+ months of living expenses gives you an extraordinary amount of freedom to pursue things that others cannot. Maybe you want to relocate *before* seeking a new job? Maybe you want to buy a new home without the stress of having to concurrently sell your current home. Take a sabbatical. Go back to school. Take the family to Europe for the summer. These things simply can't be done on 3 months savings.

Comment: Please remember comments are for clarifying the question, not for answers or extended discussion that's only peripherally relevant.

Comment: @Mars but nobody is ever *guaranteed* credit, at least not on agreeable terms :) Sure, I have a 790 credit score and ~$150K of equity in real estate among other assets. It seems like I can probably always access some of that "for emergencies" if needed, but it will be harder to access if I lose my job for some reason (and harder to repay!), or if the market takes a downturn, and it will be less appealing at rates of 8 or 9% versus the current 3.5%.  IMO: 3 months = "emergency fund", whereas 6-12 months provides for much more than just "emergencies".

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why, if only the washer broke, you had to buy a new dryer too. That probably cost you $1000 right there.

Comment: @DavidZ - Mars is likely referring to your credit cards. With your credit and income, you should easily be able to get $50K or even $100K limit spread across several cards.

Comment: @DavidZ anything beyond the 3 month emergency fund is a lower priority. How exactly you weigh paying off lower interest debt vs investing (and how conservative/aggressive that investing is) is a separate discussion, but you definitely shouldn't be holding 12+ months of living expenses in cash. Its just a waste.

Comment: @Dunk yes we have approximately $100K of total credit, between the HELOC and a few credit cards (I did not list several accounts which have $0 balance).

Comment: @mbrig Good points, and I agree. "Cash" is an oversimplification, I suppose when I envision 6-12 months of expenses I mean simply liquid assets. Any sort of interest-bearing investment that can easily be converted to cash. I would keep 3 months cash and the remainder in some other investable asset(s).

Comment: *$300 towards some life insurance policies* Is that per month? If so I would replace that with a cheaper term life insurance policy, the remainder of that money could be better used elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidBrown yes, per month. We each have a 20 year level term policy ($250K) *and* an adjustable hybrid policy ($100K). Monthly premiums for mine are $25 and $92, respectively.

Comment: Every one of the things you listed for doing with the emergency fund sound's like it should be a totally separate fund and would probably raise a new question on this site: "Is it advisable to take a sabbatical when I'm currently paying >$800 a month in interest alone?" As @Dunk pointed out, your cards alone should be a huge safety net for you, without costing you anything simply to have them.

Comment: Again, I could be missing something fundamental here, but I think any investment returning less than the rate of interest on your highest rated debt (currently 5%, later up to 8.5% i believe you said?) is essentially just burning money

Comment: @Mars you're fundamentally correct regarding investments vs. debts, though I reject the idea that credit cards are a "safety net" -- charitably, of course it's better than *nothing*, but they're inferior by an order of magnitude to equity loans, inferior to an unsecured LOC I have ($0 balance), and inferior to cash/equivalent. The condo, however, has an 11-year rental history with like a 98% occupancy rate. Rent covers the mortgage/taxes/insurance/dues, but we are exposed to some risk from damage, required renovations, etc.

Comment: @DavidZ Those other lines of credit are certainly even better, which just strengthens my point that you have better options than holding onto cash. I'm glad the condo is also covering itself as well. I'm sure it also has a lot of intangible value in terms of peace of mind, etc. Hopefully it also has a little bit of positive cash flow as well (not just breaking even). But strictly speaking numbers, I believe if it's just breaking even, if it's (appreciation + cashflow - damage - renovations - etc - inoccupancy - management hours) aren't greater than 4-8% per year, it's again burning money.

Comment: @Mars yes, I see your point for sure. I'm not trying to fetishize cash-holdings (certainly not in the short-term). Certainly for the next 6 months minimum I need to handle those immediate expenses & credit card balances before I can think about really building that up or paying anything else down (both, ideally!).

Comment: > credit cards are my emergency fund @Mars — that’s called "being ready for the next recession"... seriously you do not remember 2008? Or do you believe market conditions now are not like 2006?

Comment: @Mars I tend to agree. I have less than €2k liquid at any time (even less than 1k right now) because every other paycheck I'm at the bank to pay 2500+ back on my loan. If I have an emergency I have a line of credit that allows me to open a loan up to 5K and get the money in real time, no approval needed, and the interest is only 2% more than the main loan I'm trying to pay back (way, way lower than a revolving CC, less than half). Having the line open is free. Why wouldn't I use it to my advantage?

Comment: $2000 for a new water heater? Must be a tankless on demand unit or a heat pump one, otherwise a regular electric 50gal water heater should be less than $500 and gas not much more. And 25 year expected life of an expensive washer/dryer? (maybe 50 years ago), now days you are just dreaming, if anything with the extra complexity, an expensive unit will not last as long as a basic one.

Comment: @GlenYates the HWH might not have been $2K, thinking back a year ago it was probably closer to $1500 installed. We required the more expensive "power vent" style -- this was not a choice, believe me I'd rather have bought a $499 unit but it simply was not an option. there is no "extra complexity", in fact, the units we bought are considerably *less* complex, and AFAIK the only brand that still makes them that way. No plastic parts, no digital doohickeys, all mechanical, and their service-life is their key selling point.

Comment: @Harper Nope, sorry, I wasn't born yet. I assume that the recession didn't happen overnight though, and that credit card companies granted some advance notice before reducing credit limits--some minimal amount of time allowing for other preparations.

Comment: But now that I think about it, if OP's income is ~120k (not including the rental), 30-35k is more like a 3 month buffer than 6...maybe it's stretchable to 6? Depends on the total of minimum payments....

Answer (score 26):

The bottom line is you are flirting with debt, much like I did during my younger years.  Many ill-informed people will tell you to continue to march, build wealth by using other people's money.  However, they never talk about the downside of doing so and the series of events that can lead to bankruptcy or near so.

For the most part you are not doing bad, you are just ill-informed.  Debt increase risk that is seldom talked about and IMHO, you are way too extended.  What seems to support this opinion is the tone of your question.

This may sound really radical, but I would sell the rental property.  Paying off your debts smallest to largest until the Student Loans and HELOC is gone.  Only then would I think about jumping back into the "investment property business" and only do so with cash.  That is buy rental properties with cash only.

Selling the rental removes a lot of risk from your life and it would probably make you feel much more comfortable using savings to pay off your credit cards, which needs to be done ASAP.

As far as your jeep goes, you can probably sell it as is, and use the proceeds to get some basic transportation.

All this pain is temporary but will lead to better days in the future.  Do you want to be in this same place 10 years from now?  A brief amount of research will indicate that is likely to happen unless you do things differently than most Americans do.  Most mindlessly follow the advice of "Madison Ave" to their financial detriment.

I was 43 when I engaged in a radical debt elimination strategy, and built more net worth that year than my previous working 
years combined.  My biggest regret is that I did not do so sooner.

So in your shoes, I would:

- Sell the rental property and use any proceeds to pay off debt.
- Sell the jeep and buy basic transportation.
- Get on a monthly written budget.
- Think about picking up a second job.
- Use the savings account to pay off the washer and dryer and credit card.

Once your debt is gone, it will be relatively smooth sailing to build a fully funded emergency fund.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with the 'Sell the rental property' bit. It is true that they seem to be losing money right now but if it cash flows then I would say keep it. If they are spending more money (and consistently have been for the last few years) on the rental property, then there is no point to keeping it. At the end of the day I view it as a source of income that should appreciate with time.

Comment: Even if it cash flows there is not enough to mitigate the risk.

Comment: I don't feel particularly over-extended (assets > liabilities by a good margin, cash position & net worth increasing steadily, debt is going down). Sometimes frustrated by liquidity, of my own doing -- I could've taken a 30yr mortgage with 5% down instead of 15 with 20%. I might have cash but no equity (or I might have neither!), and more uncertainty w/r/t the local real estate market. I could contribute less to my 401k. We might not have life insurance, etc. I figure lot of "average" people do not do one or more of these things, in pursuit of the Madison Ave. lifestyle that we try to avoid.

Comment: Mathematically it would seem like the transaction costs would negate any advantage that selling the property has. You'd be throwing $10k+ out the window for the sole reason of "debt is bad somehow". Why not keep it until/unless something catastrophic happens.

Comment: And a note on the Jeep: it's 14 years old, and would by most accounts be "basic transportation". Relatively low miles for its age. It has new brakes, new tires, and some other bits from recent maintenance. It runs reliably, etc. I'd be hard-pressed to find a cheaper car (after paying title/taxes) that would be *more* reliable over the next say, 12-24 months.

Comment: @xyious one of the major listed un-budgeted expenses is related to maintaining the "investment" property.  There is absolutely zero indication that the investment property is a *good* investment.  There are risks inherent with being a landlord and somehow you're singularly concerned with a transaction cost that you made up.

Comment: I made up 4-5 figure closing costs that you would pay each way ? Sure a major expense that was listed was repairs on the property. But that doesn't mean it will be there in the future. Just because you really need to budget it doesn't mean that it makes the investment bad. So back to the property, presumably there's a positive cash flow every month (except for extraordinary expenses) and you presumably also increase equity every month as well. I don't see how it's a good idea to sell that without a good reason.

Comment: All we know is there is a second property being called an investment that still has a loan in the amount of $52,000 and recently an expense for that property dinged this person's emergency fund.  "Presumably there's a positive cash flow every month" then this expense wouldn't have come out of the personal emergency fund.  This whole scenario is the good reason to at least reevaluate owning that property.

Comment: _"However, they never talk about the downside of doing so"_  Did you?  is it the risk, or is it something else?  Maybe I'm just bad at reading today, but that part of the answer wasn't clear to me.  :(

Comment: @quid Transaction costs are a huge deal for rental properties (getting into/out of property + setting it up in that capacity). Certainly worth reassessing but, without knowing more details it's reasonable to expect that to make the difference.

Comment: @JohnK, I never said or insinuated that transaction costs should not be considered.  There is no indication that "mathematically it would seem like the transaction costs would negate any advantage that selling the property has" All we know is there is a $52k mortgage and a recent $2k expense. We have no idea what it's worth, no idea of the purchase price, no idea of the rental income etc. There might be a huge capital gain that could be capitalized on, we don't know. But we do know the question being asked revolves around debt related stress and inability to amass a substantial emergency fund.

Comment: @quid the OP notes $10k/year rental income and a 5% ARM with 15 years left. That looks like $850 in rent and $400 mortgage payments. If $2000 assessment wipes out 5 months of profits, it's still more cash in than out in any given year. I agree it's still a risk, but the OP seems to have no interest in getting rid of it, so it's just a distraction from the real discussion of which order to pay down the debts.

Comment: @NathanL My gripe was with the assertion that "mathematically it would seem like the transaction costs would negate any advantage that selling the property has" that's not true given the known facts.  The problem here is the risk of being a landlord and whether or not the property is a good investment requires a lot more information.  But I'll agree that most of this can be deleted.

Comment: Don't pay debts smallest to largest, pay the highest interest rate ones first.  And as for a Jeep being reliable transportation, in what alternative universe?

Comment: Paying off debts "smallest to largest" makes literally no sense. You pay them back based on the interest rate, not how big they are.

Comment: While paying smallest to largest based on balance doesn't make the most sense mathematically, it usually makes the most sense if you actually want to pay the debt off. Seeing that progress is being made by reaching zero balance on credit cards helps motivate people to keep at it. Paying down $5,000 on a $15,000 credit card still leaves a lot of money which can be discouraging. Paying off 2 credit cards with that same $5,000 gives a degree of satisfaction that you are accomplishing something. Thus, you are more likely to stay disciplined and keep paying down that debt.

Comment: @Dunk: This is the Personal Finance site, not the Psychology one :-)  The smallest to largest psychology only works if you're the sort of person that the psychology works on.  (Sorry for the circularity :-)) Which is far from being everyone.

Comment: @jamesqf - If only economic responses are valid regardless of consideration of what will happen in real life then the answer to just about every question on this site boils down to the simple answer "You should go get a job that pays $10 million per year".  Not realistic but it solves the vast majority of problems asked about on this site and is focused on the economics of the problem. OR....people can give useful answers and comments some of which may in fact involve human behavior.

Comment: @Dunk: But it's the "in real life" that matters here.  IN REAL LIFE, are there really all that many people who'd actually be affected by the psychology of smallest debt first?  (I don't think so, but that's a question for the Psychology site :-))  However, if people who wouldn't be affected blindly follow that strategy because it comes from some sort of financial guru, it costs them money.

Comment: @jamesqf - I agree with you that the proper approach is to pay off the high interest cards first. However, I was responding to the comment '...makes literally no sense'. I explained why it absolutely does make sense FOR SOME PEOPLE. Although, I agree that the question might be a good one for a psychology site because unlike you, I suspect that a large percentage, if not most non-mathematical/engineering people, would be more apt to stick with a plan to pay off their debt when they can see the more tangible progress. eg. Credit cards that no longer need to be paid.

Answer (score 14):

I think that your intuition about the tough pill is correct, and that you should pay off those two credit cards today. Yes, paying them off will reduce your emergency fund for the moment, and that should make you uncomfortable, and you should use that discomfort to motivate you to build it back up quickly, even if that means that you have to deliver pizzas during the evenings for a few months to bring in some extra income.

Rolling the cards into the HELOC is exchanging an unsecured debt for a secured debt, which is usually a bad idea. Leaving those credit card balances in place represents you choosing the known risk of being beholden to those companies over the more amorphous risk of an uncertain future. Once you're outside of the grace period for those credit cards, you're effectively paying the credit card company interest in order to use your own money, so letting those debts linger doesn't make sense. If you really wanted to, you could hold out until the end of the 0% interest period for both cards, but that seems unnecessary; it's much cleaner to have those paid off so that if something happens that exceeds your cash reserves, you can fall back on those cards and have the full grace period available.

Stepping back from the tactical details for a moment, I think that you need to reassess your spending strategy and dedicate more time looking forward and planning. Why are so many of these expenses unexpected? Yes, life happens, and you may not be able to forecast exactly which shoe is going to drop in any given month, but budgeting a certain amount for something to go wrong every month seems prudent, especially given your track record. Regarding spending strategy, why did the new washer/dryer end up on your credit card instead of coming directly out of your emergency fund?

Once you've paid off those credit cards and are allocating money to your emergency fund, the next biggest threat to your financial future is that ARM: that is a financial time bomb that is going to increase your payments substantially. You need to either refinance that into a fixed-rate mortgage or to focus on paying it off well before the rate resets to something higher. I like the idea of having an investment property that's bringing in money, but note that having it also increases your risk surface area, and it's worth thinking long and hard about selling it, using the equity from the property to pay off (in order), your HELOC, your student loans, and potentially your mortgage.

Pausing your 401(k) contributions short-term while you put out some of the financial fires that you have smoldering around you is justified. Suspending retirement contributions should make you uncomfortable. As above, that discomfort is there to motivate you to fix a problem, and I think that it's worth leaning in to that and using it to compel you to make some of these difficult changes. Right now you have a lot going on, and you seem uncomfortable with it. Don't let yourself normalize to this situation. Lean in to the discomfort. Once you've tackled those outstanding debts and have your emergency fund in place, you can focus on building wealth. Until then, you're going to stay feeling stuck living paycheck-to-paycheck.

One final note: you mention that your credit utilization is less than 25%, and you seem to see that as a good thing. Think of it like this: you currently owe a little under 25% of your annual income to other people, so all of your paychecks January through March currently go toward making other people wealthy and can't be used to build your own wealth. The sooner you get rid of those debts, the sooner you get to use more of your income to build your own wealth.

Comment: *Regarding spending strategy, why did the new washer/dryer end up on your credit card instead of coming directly out of your emergency fund?* The emergency fund is a savings account which I don't have instant access to. So I nominally paid for the W&D with the intention of paying that balance in full, once I transfer funds to do so.

Comment: *credit utilization is less than 25%* -- no, this means that we are only using 25% of our available credit. This is a "good" thing as far as credit rating is concerned. Of course, I'd prefer it to be even *lower*, but anything above 33% will have a negative impact. So, we're on the right side of that line, and trying to improve further :)

Comment: FWIW, the ARM has a lifetime cap of like, 8.5%. Adjusts every July, and can't increase more than 2% in any year. Given the relatively low dollar amount of that loan balance, even if we hit the rate cap, it'd be a drop in the bucket. I know every dollar adds up, but that loan is among the least of my concerns :)

Comment: Trivial, I know, but don't deliver pizzas in a Jeep! Food delivery is one of those things where people end up accidentally losing money, because vehicle costs end up coming out higher than the wages.

Comment: If you don't sell you investment property, at least get a decent fixed rate loan. You can have close to 2.5% now and it can only improve. Also, paying $2300 for a machine that you can buy another for $600 is dumb. Even if the $600 fails in, let's say, 8 years, you'll still gain swapping it for a new one ~4 times before you'd loose money. Even then, the new model will be more energy efficient and you'll save on electricity bill anyway.

Comment: You won't get 8 years out of a $600 car unless you repair it yourself *(which I **highly recommend**)*. @xryl669  What you can also do if you repair things yourself, is get a $2300 repair done for about $600 *including the tools you keep forever*.

Comment: @Harper: I don't think xryl was talking about the car.  His comment makes perfect sense (especially the electric bill part) if it's about the washer/dryer combo.

Answer (score 8):

> We currently have about $16K cash.

This isn't the worst problem to have!!

> I'd like to have $30-35K+ for a ~6 month reserve. I know it will take time to get there. But every time I reach some milestone (e.g., $20K, or briefly flirted with $25K) **we get hammered with some large, unexpected expense**

Wait until you get divorced.  Then you'll **beg** for the problems you currently have.

> which either saps the reserve fund, or adds to the debt.

But that's what your Reserve Savings Fund is for.

> $2000 for new hot water heater
>
> $2200 for vehicle repairs/maintenance (mea culpa, my Jeep is 14 years old, this should've been budgeted...)
>
> $2000 assessment for new parking lot on an investment property
>
> $2300 for new washer/dryer

There are two schools of thought on this matter:

1. A Single, Giant Reserve Savings Fund (aka Emergency Fund) which all this stuff is paid from, and
2. Every Dollar Has A Purpose (where you create a Home Repair Fund, Vehicle Fund, Medical Fund, Property Tax, Auto Insurance, Homeowners Insurance, etc, in addition to the Reserve Savings Fund (which would be smaller than the $30-35K you're currently shooting for).  The sum of the funds would be the same as the SGRF.

I tend to prefer the EDHAP approach, and track it all in a multi-column spreadsheet: columns for funds, and rows for dates, while all the money goes in a single savings account. The beauty, IMO, of doing it this way is that you can "steal" money from one fund to another by just a few clicks in Excel.  This also boils down to a spreadsheet sitting on top of the SGRF...

> I'd like to pay off both CC's which amounts to a pretty staggering outlay in the next ~45 days of nearly $10K (we will have property taxes & homeowners insurance due September, totaling ~$4000),

The critical bits are CC2, tax and insurance.  The CC1 can can be kicked down the road a bit.

> I could come up with an extra $500-600 monthly by temporarily (say, for the next 4-5 months) suspending my 401k contributions.

Is there a company match?  Because reducing contributions below that limit is a voluntary pay cut, and that's obviously bad.  Reducing it **to** the company match limit is feasible, though.

Comment: No cable TV or pay channels here. We have Hulu + ($7.99 annually on a promo) and use my brother's Netflix. Combined internet + cell phone bill is about $105 monthly. No gaming (mobile or otherwise). Most of our grocery shopping is done at Meijer (large midwest retail grocer chain).

Comment: @DavidZemens so much for that idea... :)

Comment: Good point about reducing *to* the company match threshhold, though. I suppose that's what I meant, but didn't specify. Wife & I both work from home, we rarely dine out and what modest "budget" I allow for that is basically a rounding error (e.g., $25/month for "fast food").  We (with the kids) may dine out once or twice a month other than that. (I'm a pretty good cook & prepare most meals at home).

Comment: I don't understand the thing that you call the beauty of EDHAP over SGRF. What exactly is the point if "cheating" is as easy as a few clicks? Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Ghanima if, for example, you have $400 in the Appliance Fund and $600 in the Auto Repair Fund then you've got $1000 in cash.  But repairing the car costs $700.  What do you do? The bank just sees $1000 in a single account.  So you "steal" $100 from the Appliance Fund to help repair the car.  You could also just take the $700 from the bank account and subtract $700 from $600 and have $-100 in the Auto Fund.  Both methods balance out as $300: $1000 - $700 = $400 + $-100 = $400 - $100.  (And next month you'd add your regular amount to each fund.)

Comment: @Ghanima As much as anything else, "EDHAP" helps you to work out which column costs you the most, and which need to "steal" most often.  This then lets you adjust budget and/or needs - if your vehicle is constantly "stealing" from elsewhere, for example, then you may want to consider selling it and buying something cheaper to run/maintain.  Similarly, things like Gym Memberships or TV Subscriptions should be assessed against how often they are used: $50 per month is great if you use it every day, but probably a waste if you only use it once every 2 weeks.

Comment: @Ghanima also, EDHAP makes you think about **all** your non-monthly expenses, and budget for them every month: tire need replacing. roofs need replacing, the oil needs changing, appliances break, etc, etc.   Once you start thinking like that, emergencies start to disappear because you've already planned for it.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention what your actual monthly budget looks like, but I presume from your reserve fund description that after living expenses and debt servicing, that you have some amount left over every month that you are putting into this reserve fund. We have plenty of questions and answers on shifting all of your extra savings temporarily towards aggressively tackling debts and Pete B's answer has some good tips on that.

I would say that a 3 month emergency fund is actually pretty good compared to many people. You may want to consider starting instead what Michelle Singletary of the Washington Post calls a "Life Happens" fund. Her idea is that an emergency fund should cover 3-6 months for living expenses related to job loss, while the smaller life happens fund covers your hot water heater/car trouble issues (she often says it should be around $1000 or so but you seem to need a higher amount). Once you have a reasonable life happens fund in place, direct all extra cash when possible towards paying off debts.

It also sounds like you should be better prepared for things like property taxes. You know you have them, you should already be budgeting a set amount to set aside to pay them instead of taking it out of the reserve fund. This also applies to cars and home appliances. Depending on age, you should always be thinking about upcoming likely maintenance costs (i.e. tires every few years, hot water heaters every decade or so) and considering getting that life happens fund ready for it.

Answer (score 4):

I see a lot of anxiety in your post. So I think a good first step would be to take a step back and breathe, and take an honest assessment of your situation. Consider the odds of you *actually* losing your job or other catastrophic or major thing in the near future, for which you would need more than the typically-recommended three month buffer. Work with a third party if you need to and do an honest risk and goal assessment.

Case in point, your comment:

> 3 mos is a great guideline and starting point. If you can get there, you're ahead of many people. But 6 or even 12+ months of living expenses gives you an extraordinary amount of freedom to pursue things that others cannot. Maybe you want to relocate before seeking a new job? Maybe you want to buy a new home without the stress of having to concurrently sell your current home. Take a sabbatical. Go back to school. Take the family to Europe for the summer. These things simply can't be done on 3 months savings.

Are you *actually intending* to do any of these things in the near future?

If not, those concerns are moot and your *first* priority should be paying off your debts. (Even if they are, your first priority should probably still be paying off the debts at least as much as you can, so you reduce your expense load.)

Don't worry, giving up your ideal buffer is temporary, and you can build it to six months if you want, once you stop paying for that savings.

> This will be a "single giant reserve fund" that will pay for large and/or unplanned expenses, frivolities like vacations, in addition to providing financial security/freedom in the event of hardship like job loss, medical expense, etc.

That statement directly contradicts this:

> The emergency fund is a savings account which I don't have instant access to.

Right now, your "emergency fund" isn't really an emergency fund at all, then.

Set yourself up a savings account with a decent interest rate that you can access quickly. Consider changing banks if your current one doesn't have a good savings account interest rate. Keep a few thousand dollars in that account for an *actual* emergency fund, enough to cover expenses for however long until the amount from your bigger fund can be transferred. Otherwise, you're going to find yourself having to put stuff on credit *again*.

> Current debts:
>
> Mortgage: $175K outstanding; 15 @ 2.875%, 12 years remaining.
>   Mortgage ("Investment property"): $52K outstanding, ARM; 30 @ 5%, 15 years remaining
>   Student Loans: $45,000 at 4% ($352 monthly payment)
>   HELOC: $22,000 balance at 3.5%
>   CC1: $3600 balance at 0% through December
>   CC2: $2300 balance due Aug 28 to remain within grace period (this was an
>   unplanned expense: new washer/dryer last week)
>
> I'd like to pay off both CC's which amounts to a pretty staggering
>   outlay in the next ~90 days of nearly $10K (we will have property
>   taxes & homeowners insurance due September, totaling ~$4000 -- these
>   were planned for, but the W&D were not!), which would basically cut
>   our reserve/savings fund to barely one month's expenses.

At $130k a year (gross, I'm assuming), you should be bringing home $6-7k a month, which means your *expenses* are nearly that. That means that your *first* priority should be to put a little space between how much you're bringing in and how much you're spending. You may have more assets than liabilities, but from what you've given here, your cash flow isn't great, and you've said yourself that you feel cash-poor.

Paying off those bills will positively impact exactly that. It will also lower your expenses, thus **reducing the amount you need to save to begin with.** Paying them all off now, out of your savings, would reduce your savings to one month's *current* expenses. But your post-payoff expenses also change. You're cutting your monthly expenses by somewhere around $400, not? The difference might not make it two months' expenses, but it shouldn't be discounted, either.

However, you *don't* have to pay them all off at once. Now, it is your interest to pay off CC2 immediately and you probably don't have a choice on the insurance/tax stuff, but you can spread out CC1 a bit, which should allow you to pay it from your monthly income and what you had been paying to CC2. You have until December to pay it off. Don't be afraid to leverage that fact if necessary. Or you can split the difference -- pay off the others now, then pay CC2 off in October or November.

Then, over the next couple of months, build back up your savings accounts to the *three month* buffer. Once that's done, beat down the other bills. If that makes you nervous over the long run, then start with the smallest balance one. Once you pay it off, take half of the monthly minimum payment from it and put that into your savings. That way, you're making progress on the bills and steadily growing your savings (though, with a sufficient balance and a competitive interest rate, your savings will grow on its own, albeit more slowly).

**Remember,** though, that the longer you keep interest-costing loans, the less your savings is actually worth, because you're spending more in interest than what you're getting from the savings account. Socking money away at the expense of paying those loans off actually *costs* you money. **You're essentially *paying* to save.**

> $2200 for vehicle repairs/maintenance (mea culpa, my Jeep is 14 years old, this should've been budgeted...)

There comes a point when a "cheap" car isn't so cheap anymore. You might be at that point and it might be worthwhile for you to consider either a new car or an alternative form of transportation. Tally up the expenses you've spent on that car over the past couple of years and calculate the monthly cost. If it's more than what you'd pay per month for a newer car (or other transportation), then it's time to turn it in. If it's not, then you've got solid justification for sticking with what you have -- just make sure to budget accordingly.

**tl;dr** - Loans cost more than savings makes. Don't pay to save. Paying them off also reduces the amount you need to save for expenses to begin with.

Comment: Hi Shauna & thanks for the feedback. It takes 2-3 days to transfer funds from savings to checking, so it is accessible it's just not instantly accessible. Also limited by Reg D (as are all savings accounts in the US) to only 6 withdrawals per month. I am a bit anxious of course -- but getting a handle on this will take care of that :)

Comment: Great answer. One thing though, CC1 *you have until December to pay it off. Don't be afraid to leverage that fact if necessary.* This is a free buffer--paying it off earlier than necessary is money that you could have spent reducing your interest payments instead. I think here, a just-in-time payment (assuming virtually no-risk) is actually optimal.

Comment: @Mars you're absolutely right, at least under most circumstances. Generally, when faced with such decisions, I weigh the pros/cons of paying off early versus running out its time. Sometimes, the money from that payment, or the lifting of the mental/emotional burden of that debt is more valuable than the interest saved.

Comment: @DavidZ I'm aware of the transaction limits, but that's irrelevant to the discussion at hand, since it was only referring to one transaction. That is also where a second account would _help_ your situation, because it effectively doubles your transaction number if you need to pull that much from savings that many times. And the point was that if there's any delay in getting your money, it's not equivalent to cash for emergency purposes, because it's not readily available.

Answer (score 3):

### Constant emergencies

There is a pattern of behavior exhibited by a fraction of the population.  Whenever they come into money, they *have an emergency*.  Which, sure enough, requires money to fix.  It's like they just can't catch any luck.

What's actually happening is that *they have emergencies all the time*.  **When they *don't* have money, they find other ways to solve them** - they simply apply their minds to it, and get it done.  And the problem is in their rear-view mirror, and they never think about it again.

But when they do have money, they are unable to access that thrifty problem-solving mindset -- their minds go straight to "throw money at the problem".   "...since I have it to throw" isn't something they consciously think... or if it is, they are thinking "Thank God I have this money, because if I didn't, *I don't know what I'd do*."

Needless to say, this is a problem.  It creates a cycle of self-impoverishing,

I don't know if that applies to you.  But you said something which sounds like it fits.

> I know it will take time to get there. But it seems each time I reach some milestone (e.g., $20K, or briefly flirted with $25K) **we get hammered with some large, unexpected expense** which either saps the reserve fund, or adds to the debt.

So give it some thought.

As an example, take the washer/dryer.  The "I don't have money" solution is either look closer at the problem and maybe fix it; maybe DIY self-repair; or get a used unit off Craigslist.

### Preparing for emergencies is actually pretty urgent

I listened to a lot of financial-advice programs from 2006-2010, and they all talked about a 3 month emergency fund, except for Suze Orman, who talked about 6. Then the 2008 recession hit, and they talked about 6 month (Suze went up to 8-12).  So since it's not a recession right now, I recommend a 3-month *yeah right, you gonna fall for that one!?

The fact is, in the boom-and-bust cycle, we are in one of the longest booms in history.  Even an optimist has to go "wait a minute".

Now a lot of people say "Oh, I'll just use *credit lines* as an emergency fund". Nuh-uh.  The problem with that plan is that in a general downturn, two things happen at once.  You have a fair chance of losing your job. And then, *credit* tightens up considerably.  That means inactive cards start getting closed.  Card issuers start paying much closer attention, and either close inactive accounts or drop your credit limit to slightly above your balance.  And they know when you're unemployed; your charge patterns change.

As for your HELOC, recessions are often accompanied by a downturn in real estate, and HELOC lenders will snap the the coin purse shut.

So before you even realize it, you can be sitting there with no usable credit.

The other problem with "credit cards as emergency fund" is that **you can't pay your mortgage with a credit card**, nor obviously, credit card payments. You can do cash advances, but the bank will cap your cash advances if they think you're in trouble. The way you do that *normally* is to use the card for things you normally pay cash, to free up the mortgage. But those are lifestyle expenses like movies and dinner out: *you aren't buying those when you're unemployed*.

So all this to say, you need to have your emergency fund in cash or something that is fungible to cash in a down market. (so stocks or speculative investments will also be inappropriate, unless its current value is 2-3 times the emergency fund you need, *and* you're willing to take a loss on them).

Of course the [Grasshoppers](https://fablesofaesop.com/the-ant-and-the-grasshopper.html) here (particularly the young who didn't have to support a family through 2008 as they lost their job) will pooh-pooh the importance of a big *cash* emergency fund... but your Ant Harper will suggest you [listen to Suze Orman](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/06/13/how-much-money-suze-orman-says-to-have-in-your-emergency-fund.html).  Like she says, even if nothing happens, the *peace of mind* is priceless, and helps you *feel* affluent. .

And as said, the emergency fund is for life-breaking emergencies, like enduring a year long unemployment -- *not* managing ordinary quarterly "emergencies" like car repairs.  You should have funds back for that.

### The key to emergency funds is burn rate

An emergency fund is based on your financial "burn rate" - the amount of money you must spend every month. There is a difference between "must" and "would like to", so a bunch of things like movies, eating out etc. go away. Certainly your mortgage and debt payments are a part of this.

I am a bit concerned becuase you are making really good money. You should be able to handle this debt easily.  The fact that you're having to make choices suggests to me that you have a fairly high burn rate.  Getting that down *now* will help you save.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a much simpler strategy without any preaching about debt. All told you have about $300k in debt. Mortgage/HELOC debt is your least expensive long-term, and it's the majority of your debt with $249k. Put that at the bottom of your priority list and focus in the following order:

1. Pay off CC2 on the due date from your savings. It lowers the buffer, but it's the best use of that money.
2. Pay off CC1 at $720/month to avoid paying interest on that balance. If a 0% card is not paid in full by the end of the promotional period, you often pay back interest on the entire balance. Don't do that. If you can't manage to find the full $720 in your monthly budget (by first paying the minimum on the other debts) then pay as much as you can and take the rest from savings.
3. Pay off the student loans. These loans can't easily be dismissed in bankruptcy, and they are the most expensive on your list (after the two credit cards if you don't pay while they're free.) Pay this loan as aggressively as possible. You mentioned $1000/month on the HELOC, I would recommend using it here.
4. The cashflow on the investment property is positive, but this still looks like your biggest risk to your savings account. If you lose your renters or have any other major problems, it will stretch your budget. It's also your best bet for *refinancing and reducing the interest rate* after the federal reserve announces a rate cut here shortly (stick to a 15 year loan, don't delay the final payoff). You may also still consider selling it since it can reduce the overall risk with your emergency fund, but that's up to you.

It may feel overwhelming to stare down 4 years of repayments on your student loans, and there is a missing piece of information in your post. How much are you paying total per month toward all your debts? It looks like you should be paying somewhere around $3000/month toward your debts and hopefully $500/month back into savings.

How close can you get to those numbers, and can you sustain them for 4 years until the student loan is gone? If so, your total debt is down to $158k ($108k house, $37k rental, $13k HELOC) after only 4 years of a tighter belt. At that point you have 8 years left on the house, you can finish the HELOC off in another year, and the rental can be paid of 3 years after that (assuming you tackle the HELOC at $1000/month and then put all of that to pay down the rental). You could finish off your primary mortgage in two more years and be completely debt free in 10 years. Also consider splitting any raises evenly between paying down the debt and building up savings.

Comment: Hi Nathan & thanks for the response. Your figures are just about spot-on, across the board. I like the idea of trying to aggressively tackle the student loans, and I do plan on accelerating that paydown (although perhaps not quite so aggressively) in the (hopefully) near future.

Comment: Why are student loans higher priority than the rental mortgage? The rate is higher and variable for the rental mortgage

Comment: @Mars, I guess I missed clarifying that there's a tax deduction on a rental property for mortgage interest expense. Assuming based on $130,000 and typical deductions that they are hitting the 22% bracket which makes a nominal 5% rate a 3.9% rate in practice. I did note that this is a good candidate for refinancing in the near future which could further reduce that.

Comment: @Mars Also, student loans are a different type of debt. Assuming the mortgage is non-recourse, if you walk away from it, that's that.  However student loans will follow you to the grave.  I'm oversimplifying it, but my point is, **the nature of the debt** is often a more important factor than the interest rate.

Comment: @Harper That's pretty much basing your decisions off of a likelihood that OP will go bankrupt. I think most answers here assume OP will not go bankrupt and is looking to be more efficient with payments/savings. That said, I believe some answers do suggest paying secured loans before unsecured in case of possibility of faulting!

Comment: @NathanL That's awesome to know. I'm not particularly familiar with the details of taxes. That said, does the same not apply to student loans, thus reducing those rates too? If so, that probably pushes HELOC over student loans (unless HELOC also gets a deduction..)

Comment: @Mars No I'm not assuming bankruptcy, that's not what "non-recourse" means.  Non-recourse means you are protected from foreclosure, which gives you the freedom to walk away from a house that is upside down (e.g. due to market shifts.)

Comment: @Harper I see. So if the market takes a dump, if the mortgage is non-recourse, the worst that happens is OP loses the house in the event of non-payment (of that specific loan), correct?

Comment: @Mars correct.  It'll put a foreclosure on the credit report, but won't create a general bankruptcy.

Comment: @Harper hard to imagine a situation where it's worth walking away on house bringing in 10k a year in rent when the remaining debt is only 52k, so i think in this case the only where that would come up IS bankruptcy. That, or disaster leaving the home+land worth less than the debt (but I'm guessing the property is insured...)

Answer (score 1):

What I can recommend from the perspective of someone who managed to build that buffer.

It takes much longer then expected - always. Don't get discouraged. I swear I should have reached my milestone at least 1 year earlier, but stuff always got in a way. Don't let that get to you - as it did to me.

Having said the above - your expenses seem pretty high, and that's probably what's hampering your savings.

For example that 2000$ repairs for 2005 Jeep. When I was saving up, my car cost less then that, and if I got a repair bill for 200$ I'd have sold it for scrap. Get rid of a Jeep, buy a cheap, reliable town car eg. Toyota Yaris or whatever brand it's sold under there. It needs to have cheap insurance, and cheap mainatanance, and burn little fuel.

I understand you're probably buying high quality things, but my washer cost 500$ and it works very well to. You can always replace it for something better in few years.

Now onto debt.

1. Reduce your emergency fund to 2000$ until you reach point (4)
2. Make sure to always pay-off credit cards, if you fail to do it even once, convert them into loan, and cancel them!
3. Pay down HELOC ASAP. It'd be very stupid to loose 200k$ house over 20k$ debt.
4. Start growing your emergency fund back to desired size by setting up a monthly transfer immidetely after payday.
5. Pay off high interest mortage if it has no penalty for that - since it has higher percentage then student loans.
6. Pay off Student loans.
7. Mortgage on investment property can stay there.

To repeat: *ALWAYS* pay off credit cards - even at the cost of savings, credit cards are an emergency funds in themselves, but can also lead you straight into debt, if you don't use them properly.

After that pay off everything but Student Loan (low APR), and mortgage on investment property (since it generates income, and has low APR also).

Only then start building emergency fund that's larger then 2k

PPS. By high rate mortgage I meant the 5% one, but I made a mistake and thought it's on a main house, not a rental.

In which case the order might be: Credit Cards -> HELOC -> Mortgage on rental (so you can sell it easier if needed, its' tricky though since it's your wife's property).

Then if SHTF: Use Credit Card first, reopen HELOC second.

Paycheck to savings account definitelly makes sense, I'm a freelancer, and I use "company" account as a buffer for my regular "salary", so I obviously think that's smart.

The only thing is I think your fetishizing big "emergency fund", when you have an obvious debt problem. I'd pay down stuff, before raising savings above reasonable amount.

Comment: Thanks for the insights Marcin. I'm working on a plan using advice from most/all of these answers. A few points: I am not worried to lose the house over the HELOC. In a SHTF scenario, I'd borrow against life insurance or withdraw from 401K. Neither is ideal, but both preferable to losing the house. My paycheck goes into the savings account first, and then I transfer monthly an amount based on budgeted expenses (I am paid bi-weekly and this helps manage regular bills against an irregular pay schedule). Not sure about point 5 -- we don't have a high-interest mortgage?

Comment: I've updated answer based on a comment.

Comment: About the PS, if I understand correctly, ROI on employer matching is usually 50-100%, making it one of the highest return investments you will find. The amount lost to debt <<<<<<< free from from matching

Comment: @Mars that's true

Comment: How do you plan on using the credit card and HELOC when the bank has closed them or lowered your credit limit to $500 above your current balance, because of the weak financial market and your personal financial stress?

Comment: This is of course possibility, there's always this joke about a banker and an umbrella.

Comment: Possibility?  Dude.  It happened 11 years ago and the market is in a feel-good run-up just like then.  And we've already been in the longest boom cycle in memory... Do you seriously expect that 300 years of boom-bust cycle is just going to stop cycling? And go "hold on, we can't have a recession right now, nobody has their emergency funds ready, hey everybody, get ready we're going to have a recession in April 2021..."  that would be impossible, but even if it was done somehow, very few people would prepare...

Comment: @Mars: You aren't analyzing it correctly.  Employer matching is 50-100% -- once.  It is a return, not a rate.  You cannot compare it to an interest rate on a loan, until you factor in the time to maturity of the 401k.  When you do that, it is probably boosting ROR of the 401(k) by an extra 2.2 or 2.4% APY -- very nice, but not nearly enough to bring the ROR higher than the cost of paying interest on a credit card.  Only if you actually intend to cash out the matching funds as soon as they vest, would the APY approach 50%.  And that requires meeting "hardship" criteria.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're totally right, I was analyzing it wrong. It's a 50-100% instant return, but much more normal if you give it 30ish years.  Still, with a conservative 5% ROR for 401k + your 2.4% extra estimate, that puts ROR at ~7.4%, which is much higher than the non-CC interest rates

Comment: Also worth noting that that ROR would approach 5% the longer you wait until cashing out. ~7.5% at 30 years, but a full 10% at 15 years

Comment: @Harper Dude. Relax. My point is - he's screwed today with CC debt comming due, it's better to pay it off, then worry about hypotheticals. As soon as he repays most urgent debts (CC) he can go back to building 3-6 month savings buffer. I myself only started breathing once I've reached a two year savings buffer, and I don't have moertgage to worry about, nad I have assets to liquidate if needed. But he _needs_ to pay off credit cards, and preferably get rid of at least 1 if not 2 of 4 remaining debts. Then we can assume situation normalized and he can start building savings again.